# Has anyone used parsefilter-naivebayes in nutch

Tags: nutch, naivebayes

I have an java application which creates 4 java instances of nutch (each instance work on a single seed URL )
all the above 5 application along with SOLR (10 GM memory ) are configured on a Azure VM that has 64 GB RAM and 32 processor.

I am interested only in outlinks which match some keyword and want to forward only those outlinks in the next depth .
reading the wiki page https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NaiveBayesParseFilter
gave me an idea that i can try this to resolve my problem , but i could not find any good example for the same.
what i understand is 
parsefilter.naivebayes.trainfile  : is used to parse the page content 
parsefilter.naivebayes.wordlist : is used to parse the outlinks
Can i use Naviebayes for my requirement , if yes, can anyone provide a more detailed link which i can follow.

lets consider a example here . my seed list will contain URL http://www.blueprism.com/investors
In Depth 1 - contents of http://www.blueprism.com/investors will be read , filtered and  parsed and passed to depth 2 . I only need to pass few URL's to depth two and i do this using customised Filter which looks at Outlinks and Anchor text for keywords (lets say the keyword i am looking for is financial and Annual)
In Depth 2: one of the URL Read from Crawl DB is https://www.blueprism.com/reports-presentations againn read the content , filter and parsed
In Depth 3 : https://www.blueprism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/BluePrism_AR2017.pdf  (keyword matched in anchor at depth 2 Parser)

In above case the flow to reach the document was not that difficult , but this is how i am trying to get to documents that i am interested in .
crawling of 50 seed URLs to the depth of 4 takes approx -5 hrs
Navie bayes was just a step i was planning to try.I am not sure can my process be improved by adapting any new design , will creating classifier help my case , if yes can you please provide documentation or any blog  for the same and can the ML created in JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited after the question was clarified**

If all you need is to look at the links and their anchor text for specific keywords, you don't need any ML techniques at all. You just need to write an HtmlParseFilter that manipulates the Outlinks array (in the ParseData, in the Parse, in the ParseResult which the filter receives and returns) to get only those outlinks you want.

You can iterate over the found Outlinks. Each Outlink contains two strings: its anchor text and the target URL, so just look for your keywords in these two strings, and replace the array with a new one that contains the filtered Outlinks.

Comment: I cannot use the URL Filters ,to be more precise i want to download Financial statements from the sites and every company will have a different url pattern for their financial statements page. What i do now is before adding the outlinks to crawl DB in the Customised ParseFilter i parse the HTML documents using keyword to filter the child URL based on the URL and the corresponding Anchor text . the output is not efficient , hence was planning to try the NaiveBayes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem is that the list of URLs to filter-in is dynamic or too large to write a regex per site. If this is the case, I don't think parsefilter-naivebayes will help you, since it uses ML for the content of the document, not the URLs themselves. So if you really want to use ML for this, you will need to create and train your own classifier, and add it to your ParseFilter. There are quite a few libraries to help you do this, but keep in mind that your parser is likely to be relatively slow.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion Yossi. I have updated my question with little more Information , can you please take a look and suggest if the classifier will be right option or can you suggest any other option which will meet my requirements